# HTML combobox with links

Tags: html

I need to make a combobox. Every option has a link, when the option is changed, the location of the document moves to that link.

I don't want to use any big JavaScript functions or forms.

What is the elegant way to do this?

Comment: you can't navigate to another page without using JS or forms

Comment: if it's oneline javascript function it's ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this

```
    <select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value="">Go to page...</option>
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</option>
        <option value="http://facebook.com/">facebook</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com/">twitter</option>
    </select>
```

or if you don't want to open new tab/window you can try this

```
    <select onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
        <option value="">Go to page...</option>
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</option>
        <option value="http://facebook.com/">facebook</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com/">twitter</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I'd argue that the `form` element is unnecessary here. If there was a server side solution as well so that it worked without JS I'd see the point, but not now.

Comment: This is horribly inaccessible.